# Map list of objects with sub array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this data structure that i want to map in an es6 one-liner fashion:

```
const vehicles = [
  {
    id: 'vehicle1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract1'
        name: 'Contract 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'vehicle1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract2'
        name: 'Contract 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'vehicle2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract3'
        name: 'Contract 3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'vehicle2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract4'
        name: 'Contract 4',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I would like to collect this in a list like this:

```
const result = [
  {
    id: 'vehicle1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract1'
        name: 'Contract 1',
      },
      {
        id: 'contract2'
        name: 'Contract 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'vehicle2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 'contract3'
        name: 'Contract 3',
      },
      {
        id: 'contract4'
        name: 'Contract 4',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

So the vehicles in list is unique and items is in one list.

I tried this but it only collects vehicles in list:

```
const res = vehicles.reduce((acc, vehicle) => acc.set(vehicle.id, vehicle), new Map())
```

How can I do this the 'ES6 way'?

Comment: What did you try ? Did you have a look at array functions in JS ? hint: it can be a one liner in ES5 too.

Comment: updated question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate the input by id and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the output in the desired format

```js
const vehicles=[{id:'vehicle1',items:[{id:'contract1',name:'Contract 1'}]},{id:'vehicle1',items:[{id:'contract2',name:'Contract 2'}]},{id:'vehicle2',items:[{id:'contract3',name:'Contract 3'}]},{id:'vehicle2',items:[{id:'contract4',name:'Contract 4'}]}];

const grouped = vehicles.reduce((all, {id, items}) => {

  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(id)) all[id] = { id, items: [] };

  all[id].items.push(...items);

  return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map(k => grouped[k]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map would be not a good choice for this type of result, Map used mostly when you have to modify and get same structure. You can use reduce for this.

```js
var data = [{
        id: 'vehicle1',
        items: [{
            id: 'contract1',
            name: 'Contract 1'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 'vehicle1',
        items: [{
            id: 'contract2',
            name: 'Contract 2'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 'vehicle2',
        items: [{
            id: 'contract3',
            name: 'Contract 3'
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 'vehicle2',
        items: [{
            id: 'contract4',
            name: 'Contract 4'
        }]
    }
];

var result = {};

data.forEach(val => {
    if (result[val.id])
        result[val.id].items = result[val.id].items.concat(val.items);
    else
        result[val.id] = val
});

result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: not working, it excluded some values like contract2 and 4

Comment: Oh I forget one thing, Updated check now.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path. Here it is:

```
const res = vehicles.reduce((m,v)=>m.set(v.id, [...v.items, ...(m.get(v.id)||[])]), new Map)
```

This use array destructuring to concat items.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly, you could get the grouped items in a map and map the map with the wanted `id` and `itmes` property.

```js
const
    vehicles = [{ id: 'vehicle1', items: [{ id: 'contract1', name: 'Contract 1', }] }, { id: 'vehicle1', items: [{ id: 'contract2', name: 'Contract 2', }] }, { id: 'vehicle2', items: [{ id: 'contract3', name: 'Contract 3', }] }, { id: 'vehicle2', items: [{ id: 'contract4', name: 'Contract 4' }] }],
    result = Array.from(
        vehicles.reduce((acc, { id, items }) =>
            acc.set(id,  (acc.get(id) || []).concat(items)), new Map()),
        ([id, items]) => ({ id, items })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner but it returns desired result and uses ES6 `Map`.

```js
const data = [{"id":"vehicle1","items":[{"id":"contract1","name":"Contract 1"}]},{"id":"vehicle1","items":[{"id":"contract2","name":"Contract 2"}]},{"id":"vehicle2","items":[{"id":"contract3","name":"Contract 3"}]},{"id":"vehicle2","items":[{"id":"contract4","name":"Contract 4"}]}]

const res = data.reduce((acc, {id, items}) => {
  if(!acc.get(id)) acc.set(id, {id, items});
  else acc.get(id).items.push(...items);
  return acc;
}, new Map())

console.log([...res.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not a one liner but it can be...if you delete all the line breaks :D

```
const convert = () => {
    const vMap = vehicles.reduce((acc, vehicle) => {
        if (acc[vehicle.id]) {
            acc[vehicle.id].items.push(...vehicle.items);
        } else {
            acc[vehicle.id] = vehicle;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(vMap).map(k => vMap[k]);
};

convert();
```